# How to determine which column is dragged in datagridview in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, drag-and-drop, datagridviewcolumn

In C# 4.0 winform application. 
I have a DataGridView with some columns, it's AllowUserToOrderColumns = true, user can change columns position by dragging it.

When user dragged a column i want to know which column is dragged and where it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private void dataGridView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var hitTest = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        string colDragged = dataGridView1.Columns[hitTest.ColumnIndex].Name;
        MessageBox.Show("Column Dragged is " + colDragged.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: i am trying this. thnx for reply.

Comment: welcome, but this is not accurate.. please try to test and test `:)`

Comment: but you have a guide now on how to do your task